# Arrays 'glued' at initialization

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

I've found a kind of estrange effect while I was using several related arrays. After break my mind looking for the error, finally I've found a solution. But I would like to know if any of you can explain me why is happening this.

My code was something like:

```
var closed =['closed', 'closed', ..., 'closed'];
sunday = closed;
...
saturday = closed;
```

After this if i do:

```
sunday[2] = 'open';
```

I get sunday[2] = 'open', monday[2] = 'open', tuesday[2] = 'open', ..., saturday[2] = 'open'. It's like all the variables were been 'glued' or linked because no mater which you change, all of them change in the same way.

I've fixed it in this way:

```
var closed1 =['closed', 'closed', ..., 'closed'];
...
var closed7 =['closed', 'closed', ..., 'closed'];
sunday = closed1;
...
saturday = closed7;
```

And now I get independent variables. But I don't like this solution, so I'd be grateful if someone knows the problem.
I'm running JavaScript over Google Chrome.

Thanks

Comment: Also take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript

Comment: Just to prevent future problems... Happens the same in Python?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in JavaScript, object types (which includes arrays like `closed` in your example) are [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28computer_science%29) to the actual object ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)). This means that if `x` is a variable and its value is of object type, `y = x` does not put a copy of `x` into `y`; it simply means that you can use both names to refer to the same object.

What you would actually want here is to create copies of `closed` ("clone" it). Since it's an array, you can easily do that with

```
sunday = closed.slice(0); // etc
```

Comment: You can call slice without a parameter for the same effect. `sunday = closed.slice();`

Comment: So, I've found other methods like:  sunday = ([]).concat(closed); reading about 'deep copy', but I'm new at OOP and I don't have clear these concepts. I'll use slice()

Answer (score 8):

Arrays are Objects, and Objects are reference types.

Each variable `sunday, monday, tuesday, etc...` holds a reference to the same Array, so each variable is able to observe changes to that Array.

---

Looking at your code, I have a gut feeling that maybe you should be using an Object instead of an Array.

```
var closed = {
    sunday:    'closed',
    monday:    'open',
    tuesday:   'open',
    wednesday: 'open',
    thursday:  'open',
    friday:    'open',
    saturday:  'closed'
};
```

Just a hunch though. Thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: To underline the point: there is only 1 array with many references in the original version.

Answer (score 1):

To get copies instead of references to the original array, use `slice`:

```
var closed = ['closed', 'closed', ... ];
var sunday = closed.slice();
var monday = closed.slice();
```